# Log message to history list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow to assign tasks to the project team after that send log a message to the history list!

I checked the site content to find the history list but it's not displayed !! where can find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `Workflow History List` is a `hidden list` that not listed in the **Site Content**

To open the `attached Workflow history list` to your workflow. try to do the following:

- Open SharePoint Designer > Open your Site.
- From the right side click on `workflow`, click on your workflow.
- Below Customization > click on `open history list`.

[image]

- From the above ribbon,> click on `Preview in the browser`.
- Bookmark this list to can open it quickly instead of doing all the above steps

Answer (score 0):

You can find the associated workflow history list via SharePoint Designer(SPD). Open the workflow settings page on SPD itself and click on the link as specified below:

[image]